# Mapping tool (like Automapper) for Matlab

Tags: .net, matlab, mapping, automapper, automapping

I've been enjoying the power of working with .NET types in Matlab using the [Matlab .NET Interface](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_external/brpb5k6-1.html).

I'm currently attempting a set of Matlab wrappers to expose a .NET API (wrapping to make the API feel "Matlab-y"). One of the things I find myself doing over and over is creating static helper methods in Matlab to translate DTOs from a .NET entity to a Matlab struct or class.

Does anyone know of an AutoMapper-like tool to help with this mapping?

Edit:

Here's an example. In a C# library:

```
namespace MyLib
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public string MyString { get; set; }
        public int MyInt { get; set; }

        public MyClass(string myString, int myInt)
        {
            MyString = myString;
            MyInt = myInt;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in Matlab:

```
NET.addAssembly('MyLib.dll');

% create an instance of my .NET type
netObject = MyLib.MyClass('high', 5);

% map that instance to values in a Matlab struct
% since Matlab's dynamic, create the struct on the fly
matlabStruct = map(netObject);

% assert that the values have been mapped correctly
assert(isstruct(matlabStruct));
assert(isfield(matlabStruct, 'MyString'));
assert(isfield(matlabStruct, 'MyInt'));
assert(matlabStruct.MyString == 'high');
assert(matlabStruct.MyInt == 5);

% equivalent code w/o mapper:
matlabStruct.MyString = char(netObject.MyString);
matlabStruct.MyInt = int32(netObject.MyInt);
```

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: What's wrong with using Automapper?

Comment: Rami - AFAICT Automapper is a .NET library, and I'm interested in a Matlab tool.

Comment: Andrey - good point. See the updated code. Thanks, David

Comment: I am looking for a solution that will help me with mapping C# types to MatLab MWArray derived types (MWStructArray, MWCharArray etc)

The code I write passes JSON string to MatLab library (compiled .NET MatLab code I call from my C# Web API) and MatLab deserializes it to it's native types. This process takes very long time (up to 30secs sometimes depends on complexity of JSON) and I was thinking about making Web API (C#) doing parsing job and passing MWArray object to MatLab. I earched web back and forth with little success.